# Why are my breakpoints ignored with GWT, Eclipse, and Java 1.6.0_14?

Tags: eclipse, gwt

After upgrading to Java 1.6.0_14, a GWT application in Eclipse no longer stops at breakpoints even though Eclipse shows that the breakpoints are active. Are there workarounds for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with [GWT](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3724) and [Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=279137). The current recommended workaround is to [use Java 1.6.0_13 for debugging](http://gbacon.blogspot.com/2009/06/gwt-not-hitting-breakpoints-in-hosted.html).

Comment: I experienced this with Java 7 b59 too. Annoying.

Comment: Having the same issue with jdk-7u75-windows-x64. @akarnokd: How the blazes did you get your hands on Java 7 in 2009?!? That came out in mid-2011, didn't it?

Comment: Early access builds, freely available then and now with Java 9.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs commonly with JDK 1.6.0_14 and is probably not related to GWT. Swing apps also have faced similar issues before. Here are some relevant links:

[Eclipse SWING app: breakpoint hit only after an uncaught exception is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027002/eclipse-swing-app-breakpoint-hit-only-after-an-uncaught-exception-is-thrown)

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=279137

Comment: Fron that Eclipse bug, it seems a workaround inside 6u14 is to use the JVM option: -XX:+UseParallelGC

Answer (score 2):

The [JDK early release 6u18](http://jdk6.java.net/6uNea.html) fixes this issue - finally!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and installed the latest version (JDK 1.6.0_16) and it is now fixed.  One of the bugs fixed in 1.6.0_16 is that breakpoints were not working.

-Chris Novak

Answer (score 0):

Well, I faced this issue and found why it did not work.

First of all please check that all modules listed in debug arguments contain entry points, that means in Module.gwt.xml you have declared `<entry-point/>` declaration. If at least one module is included in arguments for debugging but it doesn't have entry point eclipse plugin debug won't work. (Must have)

Also check that parameter "-startupUrl" with value stands before listed modules in debug arguments. (Nice to have)