# Inserting breakpoints on Eclipse for an Android program

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I'm using Eclipse 3.3 and Android 1.6. I installed DDMS on my Eclipse and tried to insert breakpoints as in tutorial https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/ . However, as I run my project, the program won't stop when it reaches the breakpoint. Is there a bug in Eclipse or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to [Amarghosh answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535915/inserting-breakpoints-on-eclipse-for-an-android-program/1535955#1535955), check also your JDK version.

There is a [bug with JDK6_u14 et u15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027002/eclipse-swing-app-breakpoint-hit-only-after-an-uncaught-exception-is-thrown/1027038#1027038), which made your breakpoints "invisible" (the program would not stop during a debug session)
Fixed in the latest one JDK6u16.

Answer (score 38):

May be this is the problem:

> However, as I run my project

Debug the project instead of running it. Select 'Debug' from the 'Run' menu or hit F11.

Answer (score 12):

If the breakpoint symbol/circle has a line going through it, it means you have the "skip all breakpoints" option selected. You can de-select it in the Debug view, under the "Breakpoints" section/box.

Answer (score 3):

My breakpoints haven't been working either.  In my debug configuration on the Android tab, I had the launch action set to "Do Nothing".  When I changed that to instead launch directly into an activity, my breakpoints started working.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to debug a service or widget you'll need to start an activity in order for the debugger to attach properly.