# For Android JNI/NDK debugging under Eclipse, why are my breakpoints are being ignored?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, breakpoints

I am using Eclipse 3.6.2 with the latest & greatest ADT (v20) and I trying to set a breakpoint in a method that I know it runs (logs messages to LogCat), but for some reason all breakpoints I place are simply ignored.

In my search for a solution, I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1536082), but it is very old and my JDK is much newer anyway, so the answer doesn't apply in my case.

Why is this happening and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Might be a silly question, but are you running your application in debug mode?

Comment: @soren.qvist OMG I am so stupid. I was running it via Ctrl+F11 instead of F11. Please post this as an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: I'm facing this issue, but I *AM* (I believe) building with debug: I have 'ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1' as my build command under the C/C++ build properties, and I'm running as 'Debug as... Native Application'. And it seems to have changed over the weekend: it was working on Friday, now it's failed: I get: 'run-as: Package com.mycompany.appname is unknown; verify if the application was built with NDK_DEBUG=1.

Comment: Be sure that there is not an unsatisfied link error in there as well.  You don't want to forget to statically link the library in the project.

Answer (score 1):

- Check that "Skip all breakpoints" is not enabled (little icon at the
  left of the debug icon)
- Check you've selected a file from the project you want to debug
- Check the program does not die on a previous step or if you are on a try catch, check an error does not make your program "jump" the breakpoint to the "catch" due to an error. Same happens with if else
- Check you're running the program as an "android application"
- Shortkey to debug is F11 or click the bug icon

Hope this helps!