# Debugger not stopping at breakpoints for developing android application using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am writing simple program to get copied string and see if its a URL
I want to check line by line debugging.
I have set android:debuggable="true" in manifest.

Code stops at first line of the following code

```
ClipboardManager ClipMan = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
String url= (String) ClipMan.getText();

if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)){
 //Some code
}
```

I used <kbd>F6</kbd> key for stepping over each line, first line executes just fine but second line just takes me to another window which says "source not found". All subsequent breakpoints are ignored and code gets executed.
I tried using breakpoint on each line of code and pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>, that gives same result and program gets executed.

I had similar code in project on ubuntu working fine, now I have moved to windows 7 and its not working.

Is "Version: Indigo Release" causing problem here?

I tried this solution 
[Eclipse skipping over breakpoints when debugging java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679552/eclipse-skipping-over-breakpoints-when-debugging-java)

But didn't work in my case.

Comment: This is still there and still very annoying
one thing I noticed is that when I copy a link then I get this error,
but if it's any other random text then it works fine.

Comment: ClipboardManager ClipMan = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
      String url= (String) ClipMan.getText().toString();

This worked. Still dont know why?

Answer (score 0):

check that you click on `step over` and not `step into` - with that the debugger take you to android source (which you probably don't have in your envinromnt)

Comment: I am stepping over, just to make sure I had put used breakpoints on each line and used F8.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not have android sources attached. That's why you get this error. Try [this](http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/) link. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am not stepping into source. Is having source really necessary?

Comment: It is not necessary. Then I do not know. Try to click step over several times. Or click step return.