# Java Breakpoint being ignored in MyEclipse 8.5 .... Using JRE 1.6.0.20 and Tomcat 5.5.25

Tags: eclipse, debugging, java, myeclipse, breakpoints

I have scoured the web and stackoverflow and didnt find anything specific to 1.6.20 so I am wondering if I am the only one seeing this...

I am building a JSP based on SUN JRE 1.6.0.20, Tomcat 5.5.25 and am using MyEclipse 8.5 . After running my Servlet a few times through the code/debug cycle, the IDE just starts ignoring all breakpoints. I have checked all - my debug settings, compiler settings, workspace settings, everything's fine. And I am running it in Debug mode.  This is the second time.

After the first time, I just reinstalled MyEclipse and created a  new workspace but I cant keep doing that. it is just not scalable!
Now I see that this issue has been reported as a Bug since 1.6.0.13 and subsequently fixed too and then reappeared?
So any hints to fix it would be welcome. Meanwhile I am going to go to 1.6.0.19 and see if it fixes it.

Some other related issues I have seen -

[JRE Bug Report 6862295](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6862295)

[Eclipse Bug Report 279137](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=279137)

[StackOverFlow related Q to JRE 1.6.0.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022007/why-are-my-breakpoints-ignored-with-gwt-eclipse-and-java-1-6-0-14)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022007/why-are-my-breakpoints-ignored-with-gwt-eclipse-and-java-1-6-0-14

Comment: UPDATE - Switching to 1.6.0.19 did resolve the issue.  I will continue to work with u19 to see if the issue comes back and will update this Q if it does. That will mean that the JRE issue has not been completely resolved.   
If it does not come back it may be a new manifestation. At any rate, it seems to be an issue. :-(

Comment: Oh no, the issue came back even with 1.6.0.19! 
This time I noticed that MyEclipse itself is using 1.6.0.13 out of the box. even if my tomcat is running 1.6.0.19. So I gave the -XX:+UseParallelGC option in myeclipse.ini as recommended in one of the other posts. Didnt help.

Comment: I have figured out why 1.6.0.19 the issue came back and its nothing to do with u19.
it is due to my workspace. I was trying different things to resolve this and once I had done an exploded and then a non exploded deploy. At the time, as I use Maven, it deployed an exploded version of my classes under the src/webapp/WEB-INF/classes directory instead of in the target dir. So Maven would pick up these obsolete classes(in which my brkpoint line numbers were not matching with new code) and as a result my breakpoints were not being hit!
Deleted those to get back on track!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Ubuntu Eclipse 3.5.2 with Java 1.6.0_20 on an Android 1.6 application. The breakpoints work aleatory and often phantom ones appear. It seems some kind of Java 1.6.0_14 bug has come back to stay! I recheck a lot of times the different configurations of the Java and Debug options; I have launched the debug session in thousand ways; I have reinstalled Eclipse deleting the .metadata folder; I have used Java 1.5.0_22; I have tried the "-XX:+UseParallelGC" command. Anything works! I'm turning crazy!

**EDIT:** I have figured out when I put more than around 20 breakpoints, in the DalvikVM log appears "ERROR: max breakpoints exceeded." and hence, the later breakpoints do not work.

Comment: I feel for you... Wish there was a more sane and a more visible error message in these scenarios.